Dynamics BC, payments and payment journals aren't showing up in production
I'm creating and interacting with SalesInvoices, also legacy invoices.
But when it comes to reviewing existing payments and paymentjournals, I'm only seeing the ones I create via the API, and these seem to be hidden from the UI everyone is using to access accounts receivable.
Why would one be working and not the other?
I tried expanding the admin credentials and permissions of what tables we're able to interact with to no avail.
